# How to stop grid cell from redrawing in Java?

Tags: java, random, graphics, colors, grid

I am trying to generate a random color(between 4 colors) for each cell in a grid. I have managed to do so but it keeps redrawing itself over the outline of the grid and other elements of the grid. How can I make it so that the colors only draw once?, while my other elements keeps on drawing themselves?
Here is the code I currently have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cell extends Rectangle {

private Random random;

public Cell(int x, int y) {

    super(x, y, 35, 35);
}


public void paint(Graphics g, Boolean highlighted) {

    int row;
    int col;

    for (row=0; row < 20 ; row++ ) {
        for (col =0; col <20 ; col++) {
            x=col * 35;
            y=row * 35;
            SurfaceType(g);
        }
    }


    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x, y, 35, 35);


    if (highlighted) {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 35);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 35);
    }

}



@Override
public boolean contains(Point target){
    if (target == null)
        return false;
    return super.contains(target);
}

public void SurfaceType(Graphics g) {
   random= new Random();
   int randomNumber = random.nextInt( 5);

   switch (randomNumber) {
       case 1: // dirt
           g.setColor(new Color(102,51,0));
           g.fillRect(x,y,34,34);
           break;
       case 2: //grass
           g.setColor(new Color(102,153,0));
           g.fillRect(x,y,34,34);
           break;
       case 3: //tree
           g.setColor(new Color(0,102,0));
           g.fillRect(x,y,34,34);
           break;
       case 4: //rock
           g.setColor(new Color(182,182,182));
           g.fillRect(x,y,34,34);
           break;
   }



 }


}
```

This image shows what the grid looks like when I take out the code that randomizes the color out.

[image]

And this one shows with that part of code included:

[image]

Comment: You will want to [edit] your question and create and post a valid [mcve], as code-formatted text , code that we can compile and run without having to modify. One issue I see is that your `paint` method above, one that is presumably called within a painting method in a GUI, contains some program logic, code to do randomization, within it. Understand that the randomization should not be done within painting code, but rather elsewhere, so that it is not affected by redraws that are out of your control.

Comment: Because you set the value of `x` and `y` in the loop part; so regardless of what previous value you have set them to be, by the time you finish the random color part they will always be set to the bottom right corner of your screen.

Comment: See edits to answer

Answer (score 1):

In fact, that's my answer: to take the randomization **out** of your painting code. Instead, give Cell class a method, say called `randomize()` that does the randomization of colors and is only called when you want it called, and remove that code from your painting code.

Why is this important? Understand that with Swing, painting is not fully under your control, that you can *suggest* painting be done by calling `repaint()` but it's not guaranteed to always happen (especially if repainting requests "stack"), and also sometimes the OS will make a request to the JVM that painting occur, and this is completely out of your control.  So painting methods should do only painting and nothing else. Any code that significantly changes the state of your objects, such as the randomization code, belongs elsewhere.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cell extends Rectangle {
    // no magic numbers
    private static final Color DIRT_COLOR = new Color(102, 51, 0);
    private static final Color GRASS_COLOR = new Color(102,153,0);
    private static final Color TREE_COLOR = new Color(0, 102, 0);
    private static final Color ROCK_COLOR = new Color(182, 182, 182);
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 35;
    private static final int RECT_WIDTH = CELL_WIDTH - 1;
    private Color cellColor = null;
    private Random random;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
    }

    // highlighted should be a boolean primitive, not a Boolean wrapper
    public void paint(Graphics g, boolean highlighted) {
        int row;
        int col;

        // **** these nested for loops don't look right
        // as this Cell should draw itself and only itself
        for (row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
                x = col * CELL_WIDTH;
                y = row * CELL_WIDTH;

                // don't call surfactType() here, but rather *****
                // simply draw with cellColor   *******
                if (cellColor != null) {
                    g.setColor(cellColor);
                    g.fillRect(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH);
                }
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
        if (highlighted) {
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(x, y, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(x, y, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point target) {
        if (target == null)
            return false;
        return super.contains(target);
    }

    // ** Rename this from SurfaceType to surfaceType
    public void surfaceType() {
        random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5);
        switch (randomNumber) {
        case 1: // dirt
            cellColor = DIRT_COLOR;
            break;
        case 2: // grass
            cellColor = GRASS_COLOR;
            break;
        case 3: // tree
            cellColor = TREE_COLOR;
            break;
        case 4: // rock
            cellColor = ROCK_COLOR;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your GUI code can call `surfaceType()` to randomize the cell when needed, and call `repaint()` after change in state. A random painting will not change the state of the cell.

Other unrelated problems with your code:

- Your paint method with the nested for loop appears to be trying to paint all the cells not just the current one, and this doesn't look right. Instead it should concern itself with painting itself only.
- Your code does not completely follow Java naming conventions as method names should begin with a lower-case letter.
- You're using a lot of "magic" numbers and values, and want to avoid doing this, in order to make your code much more self-commenting.

Perhaps cleaner would be something along these lines, using an enum for your Ground:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public enum Ground {
    DEFAULT(null), // Not sure if you need a default 
    DIRT(new Color(102, 51, 0)), 
    GRASS(new Color(102,153,0)), 
    TREE(new Color(0,102,0)), 
    ROCK(new Color(182,182,182));

    private Ground(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    private Color color;

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public static Ground getRandom() {
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * Ground.values().length);
        return Ground.values()[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

and for the Cell2

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;

public class Cell2 {
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 35;
    private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
    private Rectangle rect; // favor composition over inheritance
    private Ground ground;

    public Cell2(int x, int y) {
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2, boolean highlighted) {
        if (ground != null && ground != Ground.DEFAULT) {
            g2.setColor(ground.getColor());
            g2.fill(rect);
        }
        g2.setStroke(STROKE);
        Color c = highlighted ? Color.LIGHT_GRAY : Color.DARK_GRAY;
        g2.setColor(c);
        g2.draw(rect);
    }

    public void randomizeGround() {
        ground = Ground.getRandom();
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return rect.contains(p);
    }
}
```